# Accidentally deleted pub-cache in Flutter sdk

Tags: flutter, caching

I accidentally deleted the pub-cache in my flutter sdk and now whenever I try to run my flutter app on the web I receive this error:

Finished with error: Invalid argument(s): A directory corresponding to fileSystemPath "/Users/xxxxx/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devtools-0.1.15/build" could not be found

How can I resolve this issue?

I already tried to restore the pub-cache but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by downloading the flutter sdk again and adding web support.

Answer (score 5):

Use `flutter pub cache repair`. It should solve the issue. See [pub cache](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache) for reference.

Comment: Where is this command intended to be run? In my project or in my flutter sdk? However I run it on both, and the problem is still here.

Comment: It should be in your project. Did you get any logs from the command?

Comment: Hi Christopher, unfortunately I cannot find any other logs. I don't know why with the pub cache repair it is not regenerated. However, if you look at my error, it is searching for the data inside the pub-cache in the sdk installation folder. Thank you

Comment: Basically it downloads me all the package my project depends on. But after running the command and trying to run the application on chrome, the problem is still here. 

I'm wondering why this happens only when I try to run the project on chrome.

Comment: @xcsob Do you still receive the same error as in your original question?

Comment: Hi Christofer, yes the error is the same. Nothing changed.

Comment: Try running `flutter pub get` and see if that helps. Also, check your filesystem to see if the directories that can't be found are there

Comment: I already checked the directory. The pub-cache isn't present. I accindentally deleted it in the sdk folder installation. I'm facing the problem starting from that moment. I don't understand how to ripristinate it.

Comment: @xcsob did you try my new suggestion?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I tried the new solution, but nothing changed :(
My issue is related to this issue, but no solution helped me by the way...
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52318

Comment: Thank you Christopher, I solved the problem downloading the sdk again from the flutter website and activating again the web support.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem downloading again.

1. Deleted the SDK folder
2. Fresh Install of the SDK.

   https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos